# Injetar EJB em bean Spring

Tags: java, primefaces, jpa, spring-security, ejb

Pessoal estou trabalhando num projeto Java EE + Primefaces + JPA com EJB. Na parte de autenticação resolvi usar o Spring Security, porém estou com dificuldades pra pegar o EJB dentro do controlador do Spring. Encontrei alguns tutoriais, mas não obtive sucesso. Se alguém aí já fez algo similar e puder me dar uma luz eu ficaria muito grato.

Controlador Spring:

```
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

private UserEJBLocal repositorio;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Usuario usuario = repositorio.getUsuarioPorLogin(login);
    UsuarioSistema user = null;

    if(usuario != null) {
        user = new UsuarioSistema(usuario, getGrupos(usuario));
    }

    return user;
}

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrupos(Usuario usuario) {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();

    for(Grupo grupo : usuario.getGrupos()) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(grupo.getNome().toUpperCase()));
    }

    return authorities;
}

public UserEJBLocal getRepositorio() {
    return repositorio;
}

public void setRepositorio(UserEJBLocal repositorio) {
    this.repositorio = repositorio;
}
```

}

EJBs:

```
public interface UserEJBLocal {
    public Usuario getUsuarioPorLogin(String login);
}


    @Stateless(mappedName = "ejb/userFind")
public class UserEJB implements UserEJBLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "martanPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Usuario getUsuarioPorLogin(String login) {
        Usuario usuario = null;

        try {
            usuario = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT user FROM Usuario AS user WHERE user.login = :login", Usuario.class)
                    .setParameter("login", login.toLowerCase()).getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return usuario;
    }

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

Configuração do EJB no Spring:

```
<beans:bean id = "userEJBLocal"
                class = "org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean" >
        <property name = "jndiName" value = "ejb/userFind" />
        <property name = "businessInterface" value = "br.com.icone.martan.modelo.repositorio.UserEJBLocal" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id = "myController" class = "br.com.icone.martan.security.AppUserDetailsService" >
        <property name = "userEJBLocal" ref = "userEJBLocal" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Eu não uso EJB, prefiro usar 100% Spring nas minhas aplicações. Já vi muita gente com esse mesmo problema que você relatou. Tente esses links que vou te passar: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html | https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Web_Framework_Kit/1.2/html/Spring_Developer_Guide/ch07s05.html | http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/integrating-ejb3-session-bean-with.html

Comment: Eu consegui resolver anotando a interface UserEJBLocal com @Remote e fazendo o lookup desta forma:
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            repositorio = (UserEJBRemote) ctx.lookup("br.com.icone.martan.modelo.repositorio.UserEJBRemote");